# How come when I press "Done" on the leaderboard it doesn't take me back to my app?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I am using **iOS7**. I have connected a highscore button so when you press it, it takes you to the leaderboard for the game. It successfully takes me to the leaderboard, however when I press the "Done" button on the top right of the leaderboard, it does not take me back to the app. It does nothing at all. How can I fix this? Here is my code for my highscore button method:

```
- (IBAction)highscoresButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a **UIBarButton** action for the done button.

`UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneAction)];`

`void doneAction(){
//pop view controller
}`